# Drawing Venn diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I would like to place the symbol of the universe set (E) on the left side and the sets A and B in the middle of the rectangle with the set B with a white area (as in the attached figure).

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[shift = {(3cm, -5cm)}, fill opacity = 0.5]
                \draw[fill = Green!70!white] (5, -2) rectangle (-2, 2) node [below right] {\textbf{$E$}};
                \draw[fill = white, draw = black] (0, 0) circle (1.7);
                \draw[fill = Green!70!white, draw = black] (-.5, 0) circle (1);

                    \node at (1.4, 0) (C) {\textbf{$B$}};
                    \node at (.2, 0) (D) {\textbf{$A$}};
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Representação da relação $A \subset B$.}
                \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code more or less achieves what you want, doesn't it? There are some improvements that can be made, though:

1. One should always put things in frames when working in the presentation mode of beamer.
2. One can use `even odd rule` to avoid overpainting fills, in particular when you use a nontrivial `fill opacity`.
3. Set the `text opacity` to 1.
4. `\textbf{...}` does not affect math expressions inside. You can use `\boldsymbol` (or `\boldmath`).

Result:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A Venn diagram}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity = 0.5,text opacity=1]
   \draw[fill = Green!70!white,even odd rule] (3.5, -2) rectangle (-3.5, 2) 
    node [below right=1ex] {$\boldsymbol{E}$}
    (0, 0) circle[radius=1.7];
   \draw[fill = white, draw = black,even odd rule] (0, 0) circle[radius=1.7]
    (-.2, 0) circle[radius=1];
   \draw[fill = Green!70!white, draw = black] (-.2, 0) circle[radius=1];

   \node at (1.4, 0) (C) {$\boldsymbol{B}$};
   \node at (.2, 0) (D) {$\boldsymbol{A}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Representa\c{c}\~ao da rela\c{c}\~ao $A \subset B$.}
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the E on the other side.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A Venn diagram}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[fill opacity = 0.5,text opacity=1]
   \draw[fill = Green!70!white,even odd rule] (-3.5, -2) rectangle (3.5, 2) 
    node[below left=1ex] {$\boldsymbol{E}$} (0, 0) circle[radius=1.7];
   \draw[fill = white, draw = black,even odd rule] (0, 0) circle[radius=1.7]
    (-.2, 0) circle[radius=1];
   \draw[fill = Green!70!white, draw = black] (-.2, 0) circle[radius=1];

   \node at (1.4, 0) (C) {$\boldsymbol{B}$};
   \node at (.2, 0) (D) {$\boldsymbol{A}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Representa\c{c}\~ao da rela\c{c}\~ao $A \subset B$.}
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger's cat! It worked! One more question: how do I place the E symbol in the upper right corner of the rectangle (as in the attached figure)?

Comment: @AlexandreLoures Use `\draw[fill = Green!70!white,even odd rule] (-3.5, -2) rectangle (3.5, 2) 
    node [below left=1ex] {$\boldsymbol{E}$}
    (0, 0) circle[radius=1.7];`.

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger's cat! For me, with this command the symbol is outside the rectangle, but I can solve it with the following command: `\node at (3.1, 1.7) (E) {$E$};`